# delete file which is used by a process of deleted windows service using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd

Hi I need to **delete windows service** and corresponding files. But I can not delete those files immediately after the window service is deleted. Still the deleted service is visible in **service control manager** with **marked for deletion** state. I can not delete those files until the deleted service disappeared from **service control manager**. How can I solve this using **batch command**?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will extract the executable path (Image Path) and sets the variable `imgpath` to that path.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2,* skip=2" %%L IN (
    `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourServiceName" /v ImagePath`
) DO SET imgpath=%%M
```

Now, delete the service and then delete the executable set in `imgpath`.